# Relativistic doppler shift

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

When rearranging the doppler shift equation in terms of wavelength to get in terms of $\beta$ we get:
$\beta = \cfrac{(\lambda_{source})^2-(\lambda_{obs})^2}{(\lambda_{source})^2 + (\lambda_{obs})^2}$.
My question is since $\beta>0$ when the observed wavelength is greater than the source e.g. redshifted, we would get a negative beta so do we have to rearrange the equation another way or would the answer just be the modulus of this equation. Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for the longitudinal Doppler shift
\begin{equation}
\left.
\beta\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{v}{c}\boldsymbol{>}0\,,\quad \texttt{if observer moves away from the source}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\dfrac{v}{c}\boldsymbol{<}0\,,\quad \texttt{if observer moves towards the source}
\end{cases}
\right\}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, not sure why I was so fixed on beta>0. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Dirac Delta Yeah.

Comment: Why not exist your excellent images ?

Comment: @Frobenius I was joking 